# Select not in not working for Crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I want to select on not found. this is crystal reports syntax.
Using my patient table view.

```
Select Patient_number 
from vwgenpatinfo b 
where b.Patient_number 
not in (    
     SELECT "ClinicalAnal_d1110yes"."Patient Number"
     FROM   "Programmer"."dbo"."ClinicalAnal_d1110yes" "ClinicalAnal_d1110yes")
```

this is getting a failure: Invalid object name "ClinicalAnal_d1110yes"

But this is in the parens works by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the double quotes here are not necessary. Also, it seems like you specify "ClinicalAnal_d1110yes" twice unecessarily. Try to re-write like this:

```
Select Patient_number from vwgenpatinfo 
where Patient_number not in
(
    SELECT Patient_Number
    FROM   Programmer.dbo.ClinicalAnal_d1110yes
)
```

Comment: Take the Sql and run it in the sql client skipping Crystal and see if your sql is valid.  That way the Sql client will tell you what the error is because Crystal will not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Patient_number from vwgenpatinfo where Patient_Number not
in (SELECT "ClinicalAnal_d1110yes"."Patient Number"
FROM "Programmer"."dbo"."ClinicalAnal_d1110yes")
```

Is this clear?

Comment: Take the Sql and run it in the sql client skipping Crystal and see if your sql is valid. That way the Sql client will tell you what the error is because Crystal will not.